# Rails AJAX returns error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to understand Rails built in AJAX helper -> `remote: true`.

I have a link in a view (`views/show`) that calls a controller via AJAX:

```
<%= link_to 'My Profile', edit_user_path(current_user), class: 'user-profile', remote: true %>
```

Which hits the appropriate controller (`controllers/users_controller.rb`) with the appropriate fields (tested with byebug):

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render plain: 'profile' }
      format.js { render plain: 'profile' }
      format.json { render plain: 'test' }
    end
  end
```

And I have my JS (`javascripts/users.js`) perform an action on ajax success or failure:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

  $('.user-profile').on('ajax:success', function(event) { console.log(event) });

  $('.user-profile').on('ajax:error', function(event) { console.log(event) });

});
```

However, no matter what I try, the `ajax:error` function always executes and I cannot figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: I figured out the problem. My app was requiring jquery_ujs. Once I removed that dependency and required rails-ujs, the problem was solved. Now to figure out the details of why.

Comment: Are you requiring jquery at all/before jquery_ujs was being required? Rails doesn't ship with jquery by default anymore.

Comment: set a `console.log` and understand how this events work https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events

Comment: I required jqeury and then jquery_ujs. Once I removed jquery_ujs and replaced it with rails-ujs, it worked.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I disabled turbo:links from my app. It was causing more problems than the benefit it was providing.